Samsung top loader leaking from bottom right towards middle
My Samsung top loader model WA48H7400A washer leaks from the bottom towards right middle when spinning. It was making a terrible noise and vibrating so we replaced the suspension rods. That helped the shaking but it is still leaking. We removed the back of machine and do not see loose or cracked hoses. We also tilt machine over so we could look underneath but didn’t see anything (didn’t really know what we were looking for). My husband is ready to just buy a new one, but if it could be a simple fix I’d rather not. Any help would be appreciated!

Suspension rods are just one part.  Terrible noise noise might mean a bad bearing or something else.  Shaking might have loosen some pipe clamps, so checking/replacing pipe clamps might help.  Best is to find where the leak happens(much harder than typing it out).
